# IntelliJ : executing a program with environment variables stored in a separated file

Tags: intellij-idea, environment-variables, run-configuration

My application needs custom environment variables to run.
I have created a run configuration in IntelliJ in order to start the application. For environment variables, I have set VM options.

Example :

```
-DDATABASE_URL=jdbc:oracle:thin:@dbbdevdb0397.fr:1522:DBZD08
```

My concern is to add all environment variables in my IntelliJ configuration automatically.
That is why I have set these environment variables inside a separated file

Example : DEV.env

```
DATABASE_URL=jdbc:oracle:thin:@dbbdevdb0397.fr:1522:DBZD08
```

Is it possible to load this file DEV.env in a IntelliJ run configuration as it could be done by SH script:

```
eval $(cat DEV.env | sed 's/^/export /');
```

Comment: No, it's not possible. Related request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-141832.

Comment: However, it is possible to execute something "before launching". I thought something can be done thanks to this feature.

Comment: No, it will not be the same process, therefore you can't set an environment before launch.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

As of March 14th 2017 it appears that someone has written a plugin which allows this.

Open settings, then select plugins
In the search box search for “.env files support” and install it. 
After restarting IntelliJ you will have a new tab in the Run Configurations screen called EnvFile. 
The EnvFile tab will have a checkbox for enabling EnvFile support and a list where you can specify the env files you want to load prior to launching that specific run configuration; you need to set the env file option up for each run configuration.

I have a similar use case to yours and it works for me in specifying env files associated with a run configuration.

Additional Information on the plugin:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7861-env-file

Comment: in my case the local.env file did not take effect for the environment variable i wanted to use; i had to use "run configuration" -> configuration tab -> Environment filed to fill in

Comment: In case it helps anyone, I'm using the latest version of IntellIJ 2023.1 and sadly I couldn't get the plugin to work. However, the exact same steps work for a new plugin called "EnvFile".

Comment: It seems this plugin EnvfFile only works for the community edition, not the pro edition.  I just can't understand why JetBrains didn't implement something similar.