# Run Django tests with pipenv in intellij

Tags: python, django, intellij-idea, pipenv

I started writing a django app with the help of pipenv.

From the CLI I run my tests via `pipenv run ./manage.py test`. That loads my `.env`-file puts me inside the virtualenv and executes the test command.

Now I want to do the same with a Run configuration in intellij.

What I did:

- Created a new run configuration with "Django tests" base
- "use specified interpreter" is set to my virtualenv
- all other options are set to default

When I run the tests with that new configuration, I get errors that indicate, that `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` wasn't really set.

Looking further the command intellij uses for running my tests is `/home/user/.virtualenvs/django-proj-wQnnAIXN/bin/python /home/user/.IntelliJIdea2017.3/config/plugins/python/helpers/pycharm/django_test_manage.py test /home/user/dev/django-proj_site`

How can I tell intellij to run the tests with `pipenv run ..` so that my `.env` file is loaded?

Comment: why don't you enable the virtual environment in your project's root directory `pipenv shell`, then you just run `python manage.py test`?

Answer (score 2):

You can have IntelliJ load your `.env` file using the [EnvFile](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7861-envfile) plugin.

See the answer to [IntelliJ : executing a program with environment variables stored in a separated file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45056727/intellij-executing-a-program-with-environment-variables-stored-in-a-separated) for more details, including how to configure the plug in.